# Bootstrap table column width depending on content width, column using as less space as possible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the width of one table column in Boostrap fit the content width. The first column should span less space as possible. See below code or jsfiddle what I have tried so far.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Expacted outcome:

```
Some Heading
Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text:

AAA:   Some Text A
B:     Some Text B
CCCCC: Some Text C
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ne45y0gm/

```
<h4>Some Heading</h4>
<p class="mb-1">Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text Some text some text:</p>

<table class="table table-sm table-borderless">
  <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-auto">AAA:</td>
      <td class="col">Some Text A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-auto">B:</td>
      <td class="col">Some Text B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-auto">CCCCC:</td>
      <td class="col">Some Text C</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-auto">AAA:</div>
  <div class="col">Some Text A</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-auto">B:</div>
  <div class="col">Some Text B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-auto">CCCCC:</div>
  <div class="col">Some Text C</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">AAA:</div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">Some Text A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">B:</div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">Some Text B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">CCCCC:</div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">Some Text C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.w-auto` class on the table:

```html
<table class="table w-auto">
  <tr>
    <td>AAA:</td>
    <td>Some Text A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B:</td>
    <td>Some Text B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CCCCC:</td>
    <td>Some Text C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! and how to automatically break the column if the content doesn't fit the screen? like in my given example?

Comment: How do you want the column to break? Do you want it on a new line, beneath the other columns in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

**REGULAR TABLE**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table w-auto">
    <tr>
      <td>AAA:</td>
      <td>Some Text A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B:</td>
      <td>Some Text B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CCCCC:</td>
      <td>Some Text C</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

> how to automatically break the column if the content doesn't fit the screen? like in my given example

I suggest to don't use below snippet because of its not gentle way of coding.

```css
.table tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.table tr td:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table w-auto">
    <tr>
      <td>AAA:</td>
      <td>Some Text A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B:</td>
      <td>Some Text B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CCCCC:</td>
      <td>Some Text C</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```